# Deprecation warning for String based operators

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

People, i am using sequelize, and when i try to start my project, it gives:

> sequelize deprecated String based operators are now deprecated. Please use Symbol based operators for better security, read more at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operatorsnode_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:236:13

I am using `operators` of that form:

```
   db.Token.findOne({
  where: {
    functional: req.params.manager === undefined ? {[Op.ne]: “undefined”} : req.params.manager
  }
```

);

Already did (in the index of the migrations):

```
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
const sequelize = new Sequelize('test', 'test', 'pass1234', {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  dialect: 'mysql',
  operatorsAliases: Op, // use Sequelize.Op
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  },
})
```

But not working, i dont know if it is in the file corrects.. somebody could help me, please?

I am by cellphone and to format here is horrible